# Automatic browser launch in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After working on my React project, I run `npm start` but my google chrome browser does not start automatically.

I manually write "http://localhost:3000" are there any solutions???

Comment: It's `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: @Arkellys good idea, I thought user was complaining about browser not popping up but I think you might be right that they don't know the URL

Comment: @Codebling It could be both. You assumed they use CRA but it was not specified in the original question.

Comment: @Arkellys very true, they might not be using it

Answer (score 0):

## Wrong URL

`localhost://3000` is wrong, it should be `http://localhost:3000`

## Auto launch

If you're trying to get Create React App to open the dev page automatically, you may need to set your browser explicitly. Look at the environment variable called `BROWSER` in the [Create React App config](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/). It will look like this `BROWSER=chrome`, and you can put this in the `.env` file at the root of your directory. `chrome` might not be the right value, check documentation.

If the browser doesn't automatically launch, there may be an issue with your OS

Comment: I don't understand which and where parameter I have to modify

Comment: @AhlemTlili Read the doc.

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed, also if I want to deploy my project with heroku same problem the command "heroku login' does not work it displays me "failure of execution server, can not open browser"

Comment: @AhlemTlili 1) does http://localhost:3000 work? 2) is the problem that the browser won't launch or that your page doesn't come up? 3) ask a new question for Heroku

Answer (score 0):

concerning the execution of an application developed with react js if I type npm start; the execution does not start automatically; the terminal shows me the url that I must type and I write it manually in my browser. and I notice that a similar problem occurs when I type herroku login if I want to deploy a project. I think there is a problem with my browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).